# What is the best way to import spss file in R with value labels?

Tags: r, import, spss

I have a spss file which contents variables and value labels. I saw foreign package with `read.spss` function:

```
data <- read.spss("2017.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE, use.value.labels = TRUE)
```

If i use `use.value.labels = TRUE`, all string change to factor variables and i dont want it because they are not factor all.

I found one solution but i dont know if it is the best way to do it

1º First read spss file with previous sentence
2º select which variables are not factor and change it to string with:

```
cols <- c("x", "ab")

data[cols] <- lapply(data[cols], as.character)
```

if i dont use `use.value.labels = TRUE` i  will have not value labels and i cannot export file correctly

Comment: I took a very quick at the documentation and code for `foreign::read.spss` and saw that setting `max.value.labels` may help; have you tried setting `max.value.labels` ?  This is `Inf` by default and it appears if it is that if the following (from the code) evaluates to `FALSE`, `!is.finite(max.value.labels) || 
            nvalues <= max.value.labels` then factors won't be used.  Again, I only took a quick look.  Perhaps you can set `max.value.labels` to 0 or -1.

Comment: I would post the above as an answer but I can't confirm whether it will fix your issue.  If this works, perhaps you should ping the author to suggest documenting how to turn off factors.

Comment: @steveb 
Yes but that works within the factor, ie you can choose which is the maximum level that will have the factors

Comment: The work around I was pointing out is that if `max.value.labels` is set to something you know to be smaller than `nvalues`, you shouldn't have a conversion to `factors`.  If you set `max.value.labels <- -1`, it is likely you won't have a conversion to `factors`.  This is a potential workaround and it would be better if the function provided something like `stringsAsFactors` like other `read` functions.

Comment: but i have factor and i need it with labels @steveb

Comment: From the code in `foreign::read.spss` it looks like if my suggestion works, labels are made into attributes.  You may want to look at the attributes.  Ultimately, you may want to contact the author and suggest adding this option.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `memisc` package:

```
sav <- spss.system.file("file.sav")
df <- as.data.set(sav)
```

My company regularly deals with SAV files and we extract out the metadata separately. With the `foreign` package, you can get the metadata out in a few different ways (after you have loaded the file in):

```
data.label.table <- attr(sav, "label.table")
missings <- attr(sav, "missings")
```

The other bits require various `lapply` and `sapply` functions to get them out. The script I have is quite long, so I will not share it here. If you read the data in with `read.spss(sav, to.data.frame = TRUE)` you can get:

```
VariableLabels <- unname(attr(sav, "variable.labels"))
```

Comment: but how can i export my dataframe with labels?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you can import the data without labels, get the metadata and then do a join. I'm not sure why you can't load the data in as factors. What data is it?

Comment: yes Oliver the problem is that i have string and factor variable. If i use value labels =true , all string variable will be factor. if i dont use value labels all string variables will be character. the best solution i found is explained in original post...    how can i join metadata and dataframe?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data that it can't be loaded in as a factor column?

Comment: i need to merge with other data (with cbind).  but i have same variable with distinct level factor i cant use cbind ...

Answer (score 2):

I dont know why, but I can’t install a "foreign" package.

Here is what I did instead to import a dataset from SPSS to R (through Excel):

1. Open your data in SPSS.
2. Export dataset from SPSS to Excel, but make sure to choose the "Save
   value labels where defined instead of data values" option at the
   very bottom.
3. Open R.
4. Import dataset from Excel.

Now, you have a dataset in R with value labels.

Answer (score 1):

Use the haven package:

```
library(haven)
data <- read_sav("2017.sav")
```

The labels are shown in the RStudio viewer.