# How to import SPSS sav file with variable values, labels, role and measurement level (measure)?

Tags: r, spss

I am doing a personal scientific project and I am using an SPSS file out of its purpose, to calculate some tables. I successfully did it in C#, using spss .net library, already. However, I would like it to be easily and freely accessible by using R script.

WHAT I NEED TO DO

I am new in R. I would like to import a huge spss file with its actual data, variable values, labels, role and measurement level (measure).

CURRENT SETTING

I am using Microsoft r in MS Visual Studio (R Tools for Visual Studio). So far I installed `expss` and `lattice` packages.

WHAT DID I DO

By internet search I found 2 ways of doing it:

1. dataframe

```
dosya<-file.choose()
data <- read.spss(dosya, to.data.frame = TRUE)
```

and

2. dataset

```
dosya <- file.choose()
df <- as.data.set(dosya)
data.label.table <- attr(dosya, "label.table")
missings <- attr(dosya, "missings")
```

(found in [What is the best way to import spss file in R with value labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663908/what-is-the-best-way-to-import-spss-file-in-r-with-value-labels))

I failed to reach my aim on both. I was hopeful about the second but I got some error messages:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function `as.data.set' for signature` "character"'

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

You have installed `expss` package but calling the `read.spss` function from `foreign` package. That's why it is giving you the error. If you are using `expss` package then use

```
library(expss)
dosya<-file.choose()
data <- read_spss(dosya, reencode = TRUE)
```

Otherwise, you can install and use `foreign` to do this like

```
install.packages("foreign")
library(foreign)
dosya<-file.choose()
data <- read.spss(dosya, to.data.frame = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, really appreciate it. As I said I am really new and suck in the r paradigm. I used xpss and it worked. I have to acquire value labels, role and measurement level (measure) for each variable. (How/) can I do that with xpss?

Comment: There is no package in R named `xpss`. My answer contains the package `expss` which you have asked in your question. Have you tried the answers given by me?

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way I found after extensive search:

```
library(foreign) 
data <- read.spss('C:/Users/mmr1/datafile/data 2017 project/hand tumors 2020.sav', use.value.labels = TRUE, to.data.frame = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to use the `sjPlot` package to view all the names, value labels, etc. in the viewer in RStudio.

If you import the data according to the answer by @Bappa Das, you could then run the following to bring up a nice html table with that information.

```
library(sjPlot)
view_df(data)
```

Here is good article on dealing with SPSS labels in R if you haven't seen it - https://martinctc.github.io/blog/working-with-spss-labels-in-r/